# jQuery init function returning its parent object

Tags: jquery, object, slideshow

I'm trying to achieve something quite basic. I am using an openly available jQuery module (called [slides](http://slidesjs.com/)) but i need to modifiy it in a way so that i can control the object from the outside.

Now when initializing like this:

```
$('#myDivId').slides({
    preload: false,
    generatePagination: false
});
```

It all works, but i am not seeing any way to access the slides object later on. Like this:

```
var slideshow=$('#myDivId').slides({
    preload: false,
    generatePagination: false
});
```

Now i would like to be able to do something like this:

```
slideshow.animate('next');
```

The content of the variable *slideshow* is not the actual object. I assume this has something to do with how jQuery works.

Once this works i would be able to make more specific calls to the slideshow and therefore adapt it to work properly in my 'frontend usage environment'.

Now what i would like to have is the actual generated object to be returned, or at least be additionally available in the returned data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

**[Click here to see demonstration in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwUtY/)**

Thank You!

Comment: Perhaps if you post the code you have tried someone can point out what is wrong with it.

Comment: You call the slideshow functions this way: `$("#myDivId").slides("next");`  Some more code demonstrating what you are *trying* to do would certainly be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery's trigger method i was able to simulate behaviour of certain elements within the slideshow, thus finding a way not to require calling any methods on the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

function `slides()` `($.fn.slides)` is a jQuery method. in jQuery, jQuery.fn or $.fn is the prototype object for all jQuery objects. If you add a function to this object, that function becomes a jQuery method.

---

for using variable as an jQuery object, you should do this:

```
var obj = $("#myDivId") // now obj, is a jquery object
```

and you can use jquery object methods this way:

```
obj.slides();
```

Comment: This is good input, thank you, but i fail to see how i could apply this because i still don't have access to the object from outside, after i create it (as demonstrated with the pseudocode in my posting). I will edit my posting so that perhaps it becomes more easily understandable.

Comment: @user1018787 when you select an element with `$("selector")` that selected element becomes a jquery object, and you can use all of the methods of jquery object for it, the slides.js plugin extens jQuery object with `slides()` method, its available to be used and you can use it like other jquery methods.

Comment: I tried this, but i just cannot access the functions in the object this way. I don't get an error message from the js debug console either. It just doesn't register as a function call.

Comment: I tried your new solution (edited) but now what happens is that the slideshow object is created everytime i call obj.slides(); with anything inside.

Comment: yes, this is standard usage of jquery, for having better understanding of how jquery works, first you should be famiiar with real JavaScript.

Comment: That makes no sense. You provided example code as potential answer to my question - i use it explaining that the results differ from what is intended and you then say it is how the whole thing works. I am looking for a way to access the functions in this object after instanciating it somewhere on the page.

Comment: @user1018787 this code stops all activated animations, '$.fx.off = true;`

Comment: Thank You, but i stopping the animation was just an example of what i wanted to do. I really need to get to call those functions from the outside, by choice.

Answer (score 0):

> Once this works i would be able to make more **specific calls to the slideshow** and therefore adapt it to work properly in my 'frontend usage environment'.

Hey look... https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/blob/master/source/slides.js#L123

Does this help you ?

```
/*
Method Calls - The good stuff
============================================================

Play:
    $("#slides").slides("play");

Pause:
    $("#slides").slides("pause");

Stop:
    $("#slides").slides("stop");

Next:
    $("#slides").slides("next");
        - Uses default effect

    $("#slides").slides("next","fade");
        - Define effect, "slide" or "fade"

Previous:
    $("#slides").slides("previous");
        - Uses default effect

    $("#slides").slides("previous","fade");
        - Define effect, "slide" or "fade"

Goto a slide
    $("#slides").slides("slide",2);
        - Goto slide 2 using default effect

    $("#slides").slides("slide",4,"fade");
        - Define effect, "slide" or "fade"

Update:
    $("#slides").slides("update");
        - Rebuilds pagination 

Destroy:
    $("#slides").slides("destroy");
        - Removes SlidesJS, returns to predefined state

Status:
    $("#slides").slides("status");
        - Returns JSON object:
            {
                current: 4,
                state: "playing",
                total: 7
            }

    $("#slides").slides("status","current");
        - Returns current slide number

    $("#slides").slides("status","state");
        - Returns playing, paused, or stopped

    $("#slides").slides("status","total");
        - Returns total slides in slideshow
*/
```

If this is not what you're trying to do, you can always have a look to the examples http://slidesjs.com/ or report an issue https://github.com/nathansearles/slides/issues to get more specific help or ask for a new feature. If what you want to do is not handled by the plugin, you have to request the feature or edit the plugin code (tip: first answer is better)

Comment: This is great stuff, too! Thanks! The problem is that this was the beta and the author seems to have changed the code. The actual live version is not supporting these calls. I really tried that. Also i could not find any "status" function, for example, in the original code that is now live. However, somewhere in this beta code lies the answer, because if he made those functions available outside, something within the jQuery class/object definition must have made it possible.

Comment: Well.. I didn't tried but all available properties/methods seems listed here https://github.com/nathansearles/Slides/blob/master/source/slides.js#L534 Can you make **simple** jsfiddle for us to test ?

Comment: I have created a fiddle. I'm adding it to my question now.

Comment: OK I get it. Actually, in the code from the jsfiddle, nothing is done to handle such usage. 3 choices: 1) you use the "beta" version, you can try it and see if it's stable enough for you, but you should notice that the project is frozen since 1 year so it may still in beta for a while 2) you modify yourself the current code (which could be hard for sure) 3) you can "hack" it by faking `click` events: the code has a lot of statement like `$('.' + option.next ,elem).click(showNextHandler)` so if you trigger a click the handler will be called, it's bad to do so but it's a working solution.